# XUnit tests Could not find project with GUID

Tags: c#, xunit, guid

I have a problem with my unit tests. In my project I created an additional xUnit project.

If I check tests by `Right Click > Run`, there is no problem, but using `Run All Tests in View` button (whole tests are passed both times) I got 4 warnings, output is:

> ProjectData: Could not find project with GUID 55aeca32-6788-49c3-b345-c047d7107342
> ProjectData: Could not find project with GUID 55aeca32-6788-49c3-b345-c047d7107342
> ProjectData: Could not find project with GUID e3be655a-aaec-4f4c-b55f-1d1739002fac
> ProjectData: Could not find project with GUID e3be655a-aaec-4f4c-b55f-1d1739002fac
> Starting test run ==========
> [xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit .NET 6.0.9)
> [xUnit.net 00:00:00.61]   Starting:    Ado.NETSample.Tests
> [xUnit.net 00:00:00.88]   Finished:    Ado.NETSample.Tests
> Test run finished: 29 Tests (29 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 901 ms ==========

Any ideas what can be the problem?

I'm a beginner and I can't find solution to solve my problem (checked StackOverflow and other websites).

Answer (score 7):

Project GUID is stored in .sln file. This error usually means you have removed a project physically, but it still exists in sln file you can fix it by editing sln file with notepad or removing the project in solution explorer then adding it again.

Answer (score 4):

Removed hidden **.vs** folder and it's gone.